# multiple select box only selects multiple values on ctrl click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using a select box with the multiple attribute to give me a box options where i can choose many of them. It works but not in the way i want it. As in, i can ctrl click multiple choices, but i want to have it that i can just click (without ctrl) and have multiple choices remain selected. As of now normal clicks only selects one option from the box (as in, only one option remains highlighted).

Should i use javascript to keep the options selected on single clicks? I've tried this but it has not worked:

```
<select id="selecter" multiple='multiple' size='6'>
  <option value="1">user1</option>
  <option value="2">user2</option>
  <option value="3">user3</option>
  <option value="3">user4</option>
  <option value="3">user5</option>
  <option value="3">user6</option>
</select>
```

none of these work:

```
$('#selecter option').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
  //$(this).attr('selected', 'true');
  //$(this).prop('selected', 'selected');
  //$(this).prop('selected', 'true');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6u14h4oe/

Comment: If you want something that looks like a multi-select but *works* differently, I think the first step is to stop using `<select>`. I don't like the interaction pattern of `<select>` elements but that's what people are used to because browsers have worked that way forever.

Comment: answer exists in the linked question.

Comment: You can use one of these two projects : [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) or [Selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)